# Software to measure power draw of HP Server

Tags: hp, electrical-power, hp-proliant, power-supply-unit

I'm after some software to measure the power draw of a HP Server, namely a DL360 series. I know Nagios is used for logging and monitering but I'm not sure if it logs power usage as well. I've also tried to find the HP Server Management package but am not sure if this shows power usage either. I'm thinking my best bet would to buy some sort of device that goes inbetween the wall and the servers plug.

Can anybody suggest what would do for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a clamp-on meter, but the HP Management Software works as well :)

You can download the appropriate HP software for your [server model/generation/OS from here](http://h20180.www2.hp.com/apps/Nav?h_pagetype=s-002&h_lang=en&h_cc=us&h_product=316557&h_client=S-A-R163-1&h_page=hpcom&lang=en&cc=us).

Are you on Windows or Linux? What generation is your DL360? If you don't want to dig into the GUI of the HP Management Agents on Linux, the `hpasmcli` utility will show the power supply reading on demand in Watts. Depending on the version of the utility/server, you may see individual power supply readings or the system's power meter reading:

```
hpasmcli> SHOW POWERMETER 
Power Meter #1
        Power Reading  : 274
```

or

```
hpasmcli> SHOW POWERSUPPLY 
Power supply #1
        Present  : Yes
        Redundant: Yes
        Condition: Ok
        Hotplug  : Supported
        Power    : 35 Watts
Power supply #2
        Present  : Yes
        Redundant: Yes
        Condition: Ok
        Hotplug  : Supported
        Power    : 275 Watts
```

Comment: I'm on a G5 Series running Windows. Thanks for the link, I could only find the specs for the current series (G7/8). I'll give the software a go tomorrow then will probably mark as the answer.

Comment: If you have the bandwidth, be sure to download and install the entire "Proliant Support Pack". That will provide all of the management agents and monitoring for the server.

Comment: Wasn't quite expecting how much different downloads would be avalible...I've gone for the System Management Homepage and will set up the (3-part?!) support pack for download shortly.

Comment: You should only need the Proliant Support Pack.

Comment: Ok, I've got the PSP and it's extracted into many seprate .exe's. I've run the HPSUM.EXE and this has installed the SMH. I was expecting a bit more under the SMH...do I need to install these addtional plugins/packages?

Comment: What do you see? Did you reboot after the installation?

Comment: (late) follow-up: all OK now, can use this (although need to dig into the PSP a bit more) as well as the Power Info in the iLO card. Thanks for the suggestions